# Make a refresh button

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygtk

I Wanna make a refresh button to actualize the information from the API but don't know how, the code that i want to actualize is bellow:

```
def templ(widget):
    global templl,varil
    templl=Gtk.Window(title='Weather City Of London')
    varil=0
    print('ver')
    print(varil)
    while varil==0:
        requisicao3=requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=City of London&appid=a5d84c2b0dbdc187d1521773a2bd3a22')
        tempo3=json.loads(requisicao3.text)
        reqt3=(tempo3['weather'][0]['main'])
        atl3=Gtk.Button("atualize")
        print(reqt3)
        vbox3=Gtk.VBox()
        templl.add(vbox3)
        templl.add(vbox3)
        lblreqt3=Gtk.Label(reqt3)
        vbox3.add(lblreqt3)
        vbox3.add(atl3)
        templl.set_default_size(640,480)
        templl.show_all()
        varil=0
        print("funcionalop")
londonb.connect("clicked",templ)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Generally it's required that you explain the steps you've already tried to overcome the problem, few people will write code for you but everyone will help you solve the problem for yourself. What code have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The following is a function that when called that fetches the weather and puts it in your window. It is connected to the button.

```
# widget setup

def fetch_weather(widget):
    requisicao3 = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=City of London&appid=a5d84c2b0dbdc187d1521773a2bd3a22')
    tempo3 = json.loads(requisicao3.text)
    reqt3 = tempo3['weather'][0]['main']
    lblreqt3.set_label(reqt3)

if should_fetch_before_show:
    fetch_weather(atl3)

atl3.connect("clicked", fetch_weather)

# show the window
```